# Failed to build octomap_server

Tags: ros, octomap, octomap-mapping, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new both to ROS and to linux. I've tried to build **3d_navigation** package as it is described in tutorial: [3d_navigation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/3d_navigation). After completing all the steps to check out the code from svn repositories and calling

`rosmake --rosdep-install 3d_navigation`

I get an error that octomap_server fails to be built.

If I install just single package **octomap_server** and build it

`rosmake octomap_server`

I get the same error. Below is the log of build failures.

Note that I install packages in custom folder **~/ros_stacks** and all the paths are configured in bashrc. The OS I use is Ubuntu 11.04. The distribution of ROS is Diamondback.

How can I solve this problem?

```
Build failures with context:
---------------------
octomap_server
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package octomap_server
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/roslisp/cmake/roslisp.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/cmake/rospy.cmake
[rosbuild] Including /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/cpp/roscpp/cmake/roscpp.cmake
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build
cd build && make -l2
make[1]: Entering folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[2]: Entering folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[3]: Entering folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[3]: Exiting from folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
[  0%] Built target rospack_genmsg_libexe
make[3]: Entering folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[3]: Exiting from folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
[  0%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
make[3]: Entering folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[3]: Exiting from folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[3]: Entering folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/octomap_server.dir/src/OctomapServerCombined.o
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp: In member function ‘void octomap::OctomapServerCombined::insertCloudCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> >::ConstPtr&)’:
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:164:3: error: ‘KeySet’ is not a member of ‘octomap::OctomapROS<octomap::OcTree>::OcTreeType’
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:164:33: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘free_cells’
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:177:6: error: ‘free_cells’ was not declared in this scope
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:183:7: error: ‘occupied_cells’ was not declared in this scope
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:189:9: error: ‘free_cells’ was not declared in this scope
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:198:33: error: ‘octomap::OcTreeType::KeySet’ has not been declared
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:198:50: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:198:97: error: name lookup of ‘it’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:198:97: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:198:102: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:199:12: error: ‘occupied_cells’ was not declared in this scope
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:200:51: error: no matching function for call to ‘octomap::OcTree::updateNode(const pcl::PointXYZ&, bool, bool)’
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:206:9: note: candidates are: NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::point3d&, bool, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode, octomap::point3d = octomath::Vector3]
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:214:9: note:                 NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::point3d&, float, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode, octomap::point3d = octomath::Vector3]
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:222:9: note:                 NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::OcTreeKey&, bool, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode]
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:234:9: note:                 NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::OcTreeKey&, float, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode]
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:205:31: error: ‘octomap::OcTreeType::KeySet’ has not been declared
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:205:48: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘it’
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:205:104: error: ‘end’ was not declared in this scope
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerCombined.cpp:206:47: error: no matching function for call to ‘octomap::OcTree::updateNode(const pcl::PointXYZ&, bool, bool)’
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:206:9: note: candidates are: NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::point3d&, bool, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode, octomap::point3d = octomath::Vector3]
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:214:9: note:                 NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::point3d&, float, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode, octomap::point3d = octomath::Vector3]
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:222:9: note:                 NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::OcTreeKey&, bool, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode]
/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_mapping/octomap/octomap/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.hxx:234:9: note:                 NODE* octomap::OccupancyOcTreeBase<NODE>::updateNode(const octomap::OcTreeKey&, float, bool) [with NODE = octomap::OcTreeNode]
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/octomap_server.dir/src/OctomapServerCombined.o] Error 1
make[3]: Exiting from folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/octomap_server.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Exiting from folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Exiting from folder `/home/probob/ros_stacks/octomap_server/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10760/failed-to-build-octomap_server/) by [VitaliyProoks](https://answers.ros.org/users/882/vitaliyprooks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2011-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently working on all of it for improvements - 3d_navigation, octomap_server and octomap. Some of these improvements require changes in all of these packages simultaneously, and the underlying OctoMap library package itself. There is now a new OctoMap 1.1.1 released for testing and the octomap package is updated to use the new version. Update your packages ("svn up" in octomap should be enough) and all should compile again.

That being said, expect changes throughout the code as it is still under active development.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1